# C# SortedDictionary<of String, Boolean> где String - путь к файлу, как сортировать по расширению?

Tags: c#, linq

SortedDictionary sortDict....

так не работает...
sortDict.OrderBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p.Key))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У класса [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) есть [конструктор](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2), который принимает [`IComparer<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) для сравнения ключей.

Таким образом, если мы напишем нужный нам компарер, мы можем определить порядок сортировки ключей в коллекции.

Ниже код компарера, который сначала сравнивает расширения файлов, потом, если расширения одинаковые, сравнивает имена файлов. Таким образом словарь будет сортировать ключи сначала по расширению файла, потом по имени файла

```
public class ExtensionComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var ret =  string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(x), Path.GetExtension(y));
        if (ret != 0) return ret;
        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Как проверить:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, bool>(new ExtensionComparer());
dict.Add("file2.txt", false);
dict.Add("file1.txt", true);    
dict.Add("file2.1xt", false);
dict.Add("file1.1xt", true);

foreach (var kv in dict)
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} - {kv.Value}");
```

Вывод

```
file1.1xt - True
file2.1xt - False
file1.txt - True
file2.txt - False
```

Comment: Попробовал этот пример, удаляет повторяющиеся расширения, это нормально поведение?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, обновил ответ

Comment: @mymedia обновил ответ